# How to manage user level access in angular 2?

Tags: angular, jsp

Below is code we are using in JSP

```
<c:if test="${pms['WManageRoles'] eq true}">
  <li class="treeview">
    <a href="${ROOT}admin/manageroles/roles"><img src="${RESOURCES}images/Icons_1-03.png" /><span>ACCESS</span></a>                    
  </li>
</c:if>

<c:if test="${pms['WSmartrackerManageDevice'] eq true}">
  <li class="treeview">
    <a href="${ROOT}admin/smartracker/managedevices"> <img src="${RESOURCES}images/Icons_1-04.png" /><span>DEVICE </span></a>                    
  </li>
</c:if>
```

So how to handle same thing using angular2 ?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<div *ngIf = "{{pms['WSmartrackerManageDevice'] == true}}">
            <li class="treeview">
                <a href="{{ROOT}}admin/smartracker/managedevices"> <img src="{{RESOURCES}}images/Icons_1-04.png" /><span>DEVICE </span></a>                    
            </li>
        </div>
```